# Are punctuations ignored in movie titles?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, orthography, cinema

There happen to be many movies which are not punctuated correctly.

Since English is not my native language, I don't know whether punctuation usage in movie titles is just like punctuation usage for story titles, etc. Movies are certainly made by educated people, and they involve a lot of manpower and attention to fine detail, yet the titles seem to ignore punctuation accuracy.

Is this a norm?

[Examples](http://www.imdb.com/poll/Mz48_VMh26U/) (First eleven titles)

1. Honey, I Shrunk the Kids
2. You Got Served
3. Two Weeks Notice
4. The Ladies Man
5. Who Framed Roger Rabbit
6. What Just Happened
7. How Do You Know
8. Law Abiding Citizen
9. Eight Legged Freaks
10. Grown Ups
11. My Big Fat Greek Wedding

Comment: In some cases it can be to draw attention to the movie, sometimes to make it seem informal/casual and maybe more free-spirited and other times it can be to make words 'fit' better with with things such as the narrative or a series it belongs to

Comment: A lot of the time it's an artistic choice. "Inglourious Basterds" got so much flak for that, and others such as "You Got Served" use AAVE.

Comment: If there are "many movies which are not grammatically correct", then certainly it should be trivial for you to **provide many examples**. Failing that, the question is based on a false premise at best, and utter nonsense at worst.

Comment: As an aside, if English is not your first language and you are not familiar with "the usage of grammar" (whatever that means), then you are by definition not in a position to tell whether something is grammatically correct or not. You just can't. That's what not being familiar with grammar *means*.

Comment: @RegDwigнt the "many examples" are in the link, and arguably, they contain punctuation errors rather than grammatical ones.

Comment: @Mari-LouA link rot happens. We demand that a question be able to stand on its own merits.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is a pretty silly question.  "Be to happens there" is a perfectly "valid" (if stupid) movie title, since movie titles are not expected to adhere to any grammar rules (*especially* punctuation).

Comment: @HotLicks  If this is a silly question to your conscience, then better leave it unanswered.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK it's ok. I had to change it because some people were kinda berating me for asking it.

Comment: @Usernew - I believe you changed the question. It's fine to clarify and improve your own punctuation and spelling etc. However please don't change the actual nature of the question because it makes existing answers out-of-date. Thanks.  (P.S. I have removed my downvote)

Comment: @chaslyfromUK well, sorry for that :( but your answer's still reasonable.

Comment: If you're going to be talking about punctuation only then you'll have to delete questions: 1, 2, and 6. You could replace them with 1. Star Trek Into Darkness, and 2. The 40-Year-Old Virgin. The other "wrong" titles are based on spellings, and dialects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note**
> After I gave this answer, the question was altered. This (annoyingly) has made part of my answer out-of-date. I wish people wouldn't do that.

1. I argue with your assertion, "Movies are certainly made by educated people."  I don't think all of them are. Some are made by highly imaginative and creative people whose knowledge of grammar (and indeed simple facts) is limited.
2. You ask whether they are acceptable. Clearly they are acceptable to the film-makers but I presume they are unacceptable to grammarians.
3. Is this a norm?  To answer this part of your question, we would have to analyse film titles statistically and produce some mathematical answer. Rather than do that, you can look at a list of films such as this one from IMDb.com:

[TOP 100 BEST MOVIES EVER MADE](http://www.imdb.com/list/ls000049962/)

A quick glance convinces me that most are written correctly—including, for example, the use of hyphens, apostrophes and colons.

P.S.

One or two titles in that list have unconventional spelling but this is done intentionally and for artistic purposes. Example: *Se7en* instead of *Seven*. It serves to catch the reader's eye.

Comment: Thank you for at least answering my question. While I agree to your statement, I was merely talking about majority of movies being made by educated people.

Comment: Well, I'm saying that, in general, the movies made by intelligent people are probably the ones that use correct grammar. The movies made by semi-literate people are the ones that use incorrect grammar.

Comment: Got it. :) Don't have enough points to upvote :(

Comment: “It serves to catch the readers eye” ← intentional?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I'd like to claim so but no, it was an error! Now corrected.